# Issue in Rvm Installation, running in binary mode

Tags: installation, rvm

I installed rvm using commands which by convention should return rvm as a function

```
1) bash < <(curl -sk https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
2) echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
3) source .bash_profile
4) type rvm | head -1

    should return ("rvm is a function") // and it returned, rails was perfectly fine yesterday.
```

It worked perfectly yesterday, but now today when I am checking out rails. Its saying rails is not installed.

```
   type rvm | head -1
   returns "RVM is Hashed".
```

[Here is something](http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/scripting/) that i got from official site, but i dont know next I should do.
 So the question is:

What should be done to get the rvm installed in a function mode and not binary mode?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One possible reason might be that RVM is not being accessible from .bash_profile file so try out using .bashrc file instead of .bash_profile.

Copy and paste following commands into the **terminal**

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Hope it works for you. worked for me cheers !!

#### ===== Edit =====

The following should work in all cases :

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: you should not use .bashrc for sourcing RVM it might lead to unexpected errors very hard to trace, read this https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/faq/#shell_login for more details

Comment: whoa! magic. It took me a long time to figure out my problem with `type rvm | head -1`

Comment: Noticed the FAQ link in the comment above no longer works - this was the closest I could find: https://rvm.io/support/faq#what-shell-login-means-bash-l

Answer (score 3):

You should use a **login shell** in console you can test it by issuing:

```
$SHELL -l
```

it is possible to configure your terminal to use a login shell:

- https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/
- https://rvm.io/workflow/screen/
- for other terminal emulators you need to read respective manual

Comment: +1, this worked for me, it's easy, and it's the right way. Plus it is straight from the RVM author himself :-)

Comment: Short version for gnome terminal: (1) Right-click and check "Show Menubar" if it isn't already checked. (2) Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command -> ensure "Run command as a login shell" is checked. (3) Restart gnome terminal.